# An explicit (maybe algebraic) isometric embedding of the double torus with constant curvature K = -1

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, metric-embeddings

The following question is related to this previous question, [Canonical immersion of the double torus](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194451/canonical-immersion-of-the-double-torus/366949#366949):

Is there any known explicit (maybe algebraic) isometric embedding of a genus 2 surface endowed with a metric of constant curvature K = -1 into a Hilbert space of finite dimension?

Comment: Isometric embedding into where?

Comment: Into a Hilbert space of  finite dimension.

Comment: Or, to be more concrete, into $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n > 0$?

Comment: Into an R^n with a fixed inner product.

Comment: I’m pretty sure none is known, and it’s an open question whether any such  “explicit” embedding or evening just immersion exists.